# 401 with webclient https

Tags: c#

The following code keeps returning a 401:

```
        String URI = "https://api.opsourcecloud.net/oec/0.9/myaccount";

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        string s =  webClient.DownloadString(URI);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( webClient.OpenRead(URI));
```

On the last line. The password and url are correct. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, either the credentials are _not_ correct, or you are talking to a _very_ grumpy server.

Comment: Hmm it's not the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the proxy and a domain?

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Proxy = new WebProxy("<<your proxy here>>");
client.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password", "domain");
```